# How to make excel only change some cell values when auto filling

Tags: excel

I have a formula for calculating a sum based on dates.

```
=SUMIF('Daily Expense'!A:A,CONCATENATE("2/",B1,"/2017"),'Daily Expense'!B:B)
```

Now I want all the columns of a row to have the same formula with only 1 change like

```
=SUMIF('Daily Expense'!A:A,CONCATENATE("2/",C1,"/2017"),'Daily Expense'!B:B)
```

For the next column and D1 for the next one and so on.

When I use the auto fill method of dragging the mouse from the bottom right it fills the function and changes it to

```
=SUMIF('Daily Expense'!B:B,CONCATENATE("2/",C1,"/2017"),'Daily Expense'!C:C)
```

All I want to change is the cell value in the concatenate function not the others.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A:A is a relative reference which will update as you move the formula. You just need to change it to absolute, like $A:$A:

```
=SUMIF('Daily Expense'!$A:$A,CONCATENATE("2/",B1,"/2017"),'Daily Expense'!$B:$B)
```

Now when you autofill it will only update the B1 reference.